# gdal_merge.py not working after gdal and it python bindings have been installed

Tags: python, merge, gdal

I installed Python 3.4.0 64 bit and gdal file release-1400-x64-gdal-1-11-1-mapserver-6-4-1.zip from http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php. I found the binding from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal and the filename is GDAL-1.11.2-cp34-none-win_amd64. I successfully install these files and import gdal. However, when I run the following command within the Python IDE to merge files 1 2 and 3, I got an error

```
 >>> gdal_merge.py -o out.tif 1.tif 2.tif 3.tif
  File "<console>", line 1
   gdal_merge.py -o out.tif 1.tif 2.tif 3.tif
                   ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I specifically check to see if I can import gdal_merge as below

```
>>> import gdal_merge
```

and it was ok.
I appreciate if anybody could help with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

`gdal_merge.py` is part of the [GDAL utilities](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716125119/http://gdal.org:80/gdal_utilities.html) which are executed from the command line, not from within a Python IDE or another Python script.

Just open a command line (`cmd`) and type:

```
python gdal_merge.py -o out.tif 1.tif 2.tif 3.tif
```

Depending on your environment variables and whether you included GDAL in your Path variable you might need to specificy the full path to `gdal_merge.py` and/or can leave out `python` at the beginning of the call.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have two questions: I am wondering if there is a way I could use this command within Python IDE. I can use other GDAl functions but have problem with this one. My second question is: is there any way that rather than typing the filename like 1.tif 2.tif etc, I could merge all files within a folder? Thanks

Comment: If you want to use command line utilities from within Python I suggest taking a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. You could also use [batch scripting to merge the files](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88058/how-to-batch-gdal-merge-on-win7-in-one-command-line-command).

Comment: I am wondering how I can pass in input argument "-n 0" in the command to be used in subprocess. It seems that numeric values cannot be passed in as it only takes text values.